# What happens if $f \circ f = f$ and $f$ is a real function.

Tags: functions

So suppose that $f(f(x)) = f(x).$ $f$ is not necessarily invertible. Is it true that f must be the identity function?

I think that it is true, since if we let $u = f(x),$ then $f(u) = u,$ and so $f$ is the identity function, but I am not sure for some reason if this is valid.

Comment: There is not only the identity : for example, all the constant functions are solutions to your problem. Your reasoning is not valid because it only shows that $f$ is the identity *on its image*.

Comment: $f(x) = \min(0, |x|)$ is another example. You can only conclude that $f(x) = $ for all $x$ in the range of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Constant functions, $f(x) = |x|$, $f(x) = -|x|$, etc.... there are many functions like this that are not the identity one.

Comment: Is there a way that I could classify "all" real functions which satisfy this relationship?

Comment: @Wesley Yes, these are the functions that are equal to identity on their image.